# Extract values wrapped in ="" from a CSV in Python/Panda

Tags: python, csv

Here's an example of the CSV (and i don't have control over the way it's being generated so i can tweak things up)

```
PackingListNumber;OrderNumber;ArticleId;Artist;Title;Units;MediaType;Price (EUR);EANCode;InfoLine;ReleaseDate;PoReference;ShippedAt;QuantityShipped;TotalPrice (EUR)
2007100976;12669151;1E8085;="WEATHER REPORT";="MR. GONE -COLOURED-";1;LP;="16,9";="8719262030909";="180GR./INSERT/1500 COPIES ON GOLD & BLACK MARBLED VINYL";16-Jun-2023;="";06-Nov-2023;1;="16,9"
```

I am using panda and its read_csv and this is the result:
[png screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gSTp.png)
Sure it ain't optimal, so i'm looking for a way to get rid of the wrapping ="". Any ideas and can this be done on read_csv level?

Comment: Whats the expected output? Do you want to delete that column or simply remove `=""`?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this "cleanup" at the `read_csv` level, you can first read the columns and prepare the converters.

```py
import pandas as pd


def cleanup(value):
    if type(value) != str or value[0] != "=":
        return value

    return value[2:-1]


# first extract all the columns using the header (row number 0)
columns = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=";", nrows=0).columns
# then apply the cleanup method
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=";", converters={col: cleanup for col in columns})

print(df)
```

There is another solution: first read the dataframe normally, then apply the `cleanup` function on all the cells.

```py
import pandas as pd


def cleanup(value):
    if type(value) != str or value[0] != "=":
        return value

    return value[2:-1]


df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=";")
ndf = df.map(cleanup)
print(ndf)
```

Comment: The converters approach is cool, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**One-Line of Code:**

```
 df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.lstrip('="').rstrip('"') if isinstance(x, str) else x) # remove =""
```

**Test Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("input.csv", sep=";")
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.lstrip('="').rstrip('"') if isinstance(x, str) else x) # remove =""

new_file_path = 'new_file.csv'
df.to_csv(new_file_path, index=False, sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
```

**Output:**

```
PackingListNumber;OrderNumber;ArticleId;Artist;Title;Units;MediaType;Price (EUR);EANCode;InfoLine;ReleaseDate;PoReference;ShippedAt;QuantityShipped;TotalPrice (EUR)
2007100976;12669151;1E8085;WEATHER REPORT;MR. GONE -COLOURED-;1;LP;16,9;8719262030909;180GR./INSERT/1500 COPIES ON GOLD & BLACK MARBLED VINYL;16-Jun-2023;;06-Nov-2023;1;16,9
```

Comment: That's neat too, thanks a ton!

Comment: @jose if u like the solution, if u upvote or accept it, I’ll be pleased, thanks..

Comment: `df.applymap` is deprecated. Use `df.map` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> *.. to get rid of the wrapping `=""`. Any ideas and can this be done on [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) level ?*

I'm not sure if you can do that by adjusting the *quot'args* but you can try [this](https://regex101.com/r/iIOZCO/1) regex `separator` :

```
df = pd.read_csv("in.csv", sep=r'"?[;"]=?"?', engine="python", index_col=False)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   PackingListNumber  OrderNumber  ... QuantityShipped TotalPrice (EUR)
0         2007100976     12669151  ...               1             16,9

[1 rows x 15 columns]
```

Comparison table :

| [*sep*] | Artist | Title | Price (EUR) | EANCode | InfoLine | PoReference | TotalPrice (EUR) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `;` | ="WEATHER REPORT" | ="MR. GONE -COLOURED-" | ="16,9" | ="8719262030909" | ="180GR./INSERT/1500 COPIES ON GOLD & BLACK MARBLED VINYL" | ="" | ="16,9" |
| [regex](https://regex101.com/r/iIOZCO/1) | WEATHER REPORT | MR. GONE -COLOURED- | 16,9 | 8719262030909 | 180GR./INSERT/1500 COPIES ON GOLD & BLACK MARBLED VINYL |  | 16,9 |

Comment: I was wrapped around the concept of doing it via quot args, but i couldn't figure it out - regex is not my best friend, but it does what it does here. Much appreciated, only thing is i'm getting a bunch of NaN's, but that's all right